# How to run a SAP HANA stored procedure via an Oracle Database link

Tags: oracle, hyperlink, hana

I have a Oracle database, which contains a database link to a SAP HANA server. I can select data from SAP HANA just fine, but I can't execute a stored procedure via the DB link. The stored procedure does not have any In or Out parameters.

I'm calling it like this:

```
exec PROC_NAME@SAP_LINK();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `exec PROC_NAME@SAP_LINK` without any parentheses.

Comment: No, that's not working either

Answer (score 0):

There must be a Openquery where you can call the stored procedure 
ex : SELECT * FROM openquery(SAP_LINK,'CALL PROCNAME');

This should work i guess if you have a openquery function.